# References when compiling in VS2012 with a .NET 2.0 project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, reference

I'm bumping into a strange set of errors with visual studio 2012.

We are currently trying to update some applications that were created by one of my predecessors.  He used Visual Studio 2008 to create this application using the .net 2.0 framework.

Whenever I open this application in VS2012 and try to compile it, I get about 20 errors that say:

```
Error 43 The type or namespace name 'AjaxControlToolkit' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The annoying thing about this is the references are all there, intellisense even sees them.  You can start typing in any of the classes that are referenced, and VS will fill it in, yet when you run it, it says it can't find the reference.  Round and Round we go.

I've tried removing and reloading the references, I've checked to make sure all of the frameworks are selecting .net 2.0 in all files, and I've dug all over google for an answer without successes.

has anyone else bumped into this before?

Comment: From that description, you're almost certainly targeting the Client Profile.

Comment: Are the references both in the project(s) and the related `.cs` files?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies!  I'm new to asp.net, though not new to programming.  Visual Studio is taking some getting used to, though!  When you say 'targeting the client profile', I assume you mean which framework I'm targeting?  I'm currently targeting '.NET Framework 2.0' in the application properties.  The reference is in the project, but where would it be in the .cs files?  And also, what syntax would you use to set it up?  Thanks!!

Comment: I was able to get the application to compile.  Apparently, it was designed with .net 4.0 in mind instead of 2.0.  That isn't what I expected, but at least it's trying to work now.